# Read file and do below command

Tags: shell-script

From the 2 different web page the output goes to a single file called "traffic"
From one page it always has a string "sqr" and from the other page it does not have the sqr string but "attach"

So:

read file traffic
if it contains "sqr"
then do the below 3 piece of code
or 
if it contains "attach"
do the below 4 piece of code

Comment: smells like homework

Comment: You're not asking for help, you're asking us to write your script for you. What have you done? What have you tried? Post examples of your input and desired output (we can;t understand from your description) and also post what you have tried so far so we don't start from 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` to determine whether a file contains a string or not. You can put the output of `grep` into a variable by using this syntax:

```
myvariable=$(grep string file)
```

Then use a conditional (`if`) to handle the results.

#### Example

```
$ if grep -q string file; then echo "found it"; fi
```